# Using negative lookup in a regex is not working

Tags: python, regex

I want to match with every occurrence of <any_string>.verify unless it is followed by <any_string>.print, I then need to insert a specific string after <any_string>.verify. I used negative lookup to form that regex

```
((?!.+\n+.+print)(\s*([^\s]+)\.verify\n+)(.+))
```

and it worked perfectly fine when I testes it using [pythex](https://pythex.org/) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/) . It matched with

```
class.verify
class.try
```

and didn't match with

```
class.verify
class.print
```

However running this code locally on my machine

```
str='''
class.verify
class.print
    '''
print(re.findall(r'((?!.+\n+.+print)(\s*([^\s]+)\.verify\n+)(.+))',str))
```

printed

```
[('\nclass.verify\nclass.print', '\nclass.verify\n', 'class', 'class.print')]
```

Why would that regex work on an online regex tester and fail on my machine? and what is the issue with that regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a line that ends with `.verify` and the next line should not contain `.print` you can use a negative lookahead at the start of the next line.

Capture the part before and after in group 1 and group 2, and use those groups in the replacement using re.sub instead of re.findall.

```
^(\S+\.verify)(\n(?!.+\.print\b).+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qQG1h/1)

```
import re

regex = r"^(\S+\.verify)(\n(?!.+\.print\b).+)"

s = ("class.verify\n"
     "class.try\n\n"
     "class.verify\n"
     "class.print")


result = re.sub(regex, r"\1 text here\2", s, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
class.verify text here
class.try

class.verify
class.print
```